# PostgreSQL Need to make TOTAL ROW

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, row

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyF2C.png)Hello I'm Begginer and I need some help, I have this code in my SQL database

```
SELECT round(SUM(Cena)::NUMERIC,2) AS CelkovaCena, a.Meno, a.Priezvisko,Nazov
FROM Predstavenie
JOIN Autor a ON Predstavenie.ID_Autor = a.ID_Autor
WHERE a.Meno = 'Juraj' AND a.Priezvisko = 'Klein'
GROUP BY a.Meno,a.Priezvisko,Nazov;
```

This is what i get after i run this SELECT.

```
2.2 |    Juraj   |  Klein  |    Po východe slnka
5.4 |    Juraj   |  Klein  |    Ako išiel Ferenc po hlavnej
0.5 |    Juraj   |  Klein  |    Protialkoholické hnutie Klein Ferenc PHKF
```

I need to make total row below, from col "cena". I need to have something like this.

```
2.2 |    Juraj   |  Klein  |    Po východe slnka
5.4 |    Juraj   |  Klein  |    Ako išiel Ferenc po hlavnej
0.5 |    Juraj   |  Klein  |    Protialkoholické hnutie Klein Ferenc PHKF
8.1 |                      |                          |
```

Rollup doesnt seem to work because of groups. I looked up on internet for various solutions, but none of them works... Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you try `rollup`?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GROUPING SETS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/queries-table-expressions.html#queries-grouping-sets):

```
SELECT round(SUM(Cena)::NUMERIC,2) AS CelkovaCena, a.Meno,
       a.Priezvisko, Nazov
FROM Predstavenie p JOIN
     Autor a
     ON p.ID_Autor = a.ID_Autor
WHERE a.Meno = 'Juraj' AND a.Priezvisko = 'Klein'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a.Meno, a.Priezvisko, Nazov), ());
```

This is like `ROLLUP` but it allows you to explicitly list the summary rows that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Combining `WITH` and `UNION` can get you what you need if you put this in a subquery.

```
WITH subq AS (SELECT round(SUM(Cena)::NUMERIC,2) AS CelkovaCena, a.Meno, a.Priezvisko,Nazov
FROM Predstavenie
JOIN Autor a ON Predstavenie.ID_Autor = a.ID_Autor
WHERE a.Meno = 'Juraj' AND a.Priezvisko = 'Klein'
GROUP BY a.Meno,a.Priezvisko,Nazov)
SELECT * FROM subq
UNION
SELECT SUM(CelkovaCena), '', '', '' FROM subq;
```

This saves you having to get the results twice and slowing things down unnecessarily. Just make sure every `SELECT` has the same number and type of columns as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

on the fast way

```
SELECT round(SUM(Cena)::NUMERIC,2) AS CelkovaCena, a.Meno, a.Priezvisko,Nazov
FROM Predstavenie
JOIN Autor a ON Predstavenie.ID_Autor = a.ID_Autor
WHERE a.Meno = 'Juraj' AND a.Priezvisko = 'Klein'
GROUP BY a.Meno,a.Priezvisko,Nazov
union all
SELECT round(SUM(Cena)::NUMERIC,2) AS CelkovaCena,null as Meno,null as Nazov
FROM Predstavenie
JOIN Autor a ON Predstavenie.ID_Autor = a.ID_Autor
WHERE a.Meno = 'Juraj' AND a.Priezvisko = 'Klein'
```

but better approach is create new query to calculate total